# .NET Core 5 and AutoMapper : map complex nested objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

```
public class Root
{
    public List<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }   
}

public class Quote
{
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string FromCode { get; set; }
    public string ToCode { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Ask { get; set; }  
    //This will match with Price in Quote class

    public ChildModel FromId { get; set; }  
    //This will be matching with Id in ChildModel over FromCode in Quote class. Maybe something like this. List<childModel>.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == Quote.FromCode).Id

    public ChildModel ToId { get; set; } 
    //This will be matching with Id in ChildModel over ToCode in Quote class. Maybe something like this. List<childModel>.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == Quote.ToCode).Id

    public DateTime LastRequestDate { get; set; } 
    //This will match with RequestDate in Root class (for example 2 roots and 10+10=20 Quotes, first 10 Quotes will have same LastRequestDate and second 10 Qutoes will have different LastRequestDate)
    
    //...Navigation Properties to ChildModel
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    
    //...Navigation Properties to BaseModel
}
```

I have a `List<Root>` and i wanna map this with a `List<BaseModel>`

In my hand I have a `List<ChildModel>` which I should use for checking a quote's `FromCode`, `ToCode` properties and take their `Id`s from ChildModel

I tried many things for mapping this Models but I didn't succeed.

I tried something like this with `ValueTuple`:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
        CreateMap<(Root r, List<ChildModel> c), BaseModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.LastRequestDate, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.r.RequestDate));

        CreateMap<(Quote q, List<ChildModel> c), BaseModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Ask, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.q.Price))
            .ForMember(x => x.FromId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.c.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Code == z.q.FromCode).Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.ToId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.c.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Code == z.q.ToCode).Id));
}
```

And I called it in my service with `ValueTuple`:

```
List<BaseModel> list = _mapper.Map<List<BaseModel>>((listOfRoot, listOfChildEntity));
```

I probably did many things wrong. But my head is burned. I couldn't handle with this complex models. I am a newbie to the .NET world. Please can you help me?

How can I automap these models?

**EDIT :**

I did something and its works. But it didnt satisfied me. Maybe you can have better solutions.

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{
        CreateMap<(List<Root> r, List<ChildModel> c), List<BaseModel>>().ConvertUsing<CustomConverter>();

        CreateMap<(Quote q, List<ChildModel> c), BaseModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Ask, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.q.Price))
            .ForMember(x => x.FromId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.c.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Code == z.q.FromCode).Id))
            .ForMember(x => x.ToId, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.c.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Code == z.q.ToCode).Id));
}

public class CustomConverter : ITypeConverter<(List<Root> r,List<ChildModel> c), List<BaseModel>>
{
    public List<BaseModel> Convert((List<Root> r, List<ChildModel> c) source, List<BaseModel> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Equals(default) || source.r == null || source.c == null)
            return null;

        destination = new List<BaseModel>();
        foreach (var root in source.r.Select((r, i) => (r, i)))
        {
            foreach (var quote in root.r.Quotes.Select((q, j) => (q, j)))
            {
                destination.Add(context.Mapper.Map<(Quote, List<ChildModel>), BaseModel>((quote.q, source.c)));
                destination[quote.j + root.i * root.r.Quotes.Count].LastRequestDate = root.r.RequestDate;
            }
        }
        return destination;
    }
}
```

And call it inside your services with the instance of IMapper Interface.

```
List<BaseModel> list = _mapper.Map<List<BaseModel>>((listOfRoot, listOfChildModel));
```

Its is working but this looks to me totally mess. How can i save myself from this bunch of codes i don't know.

Any solutions or recommendations? Can you help guys?

Comment: Hi, generally AutoMapper works best for simple scenarios. Of course, it can tackle the more complex ones, but there is a cost to it. Maintenance and readability. If you would not be the author of this code, but a person trying to understand it for the first time, would you rather find a dedicated mapping service that handles the logic you presented above or find that logic scattered in AutoMapper maps and a custom type converter? AutoMapper can map virtually anything, it does not mean that it is always the right tool for the job. It suits best for mapping object with similar properties.

Comment: @Prolog So sir you are saying that its better for doing this manually? I am just literally trying to do this with automapper since 24 hours.